# float Point math in Unix shell script and assign it to variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have been doing integer calculation like this.

```
a=12
b=23
c=$((a-b))
echo $c
```

But, now for float numbers its is failing
i read that we can do that using bc however i want to assign the result in variable at the end.

```
a=12.7
b=23.33
c=$((a-b)) | bc
echo $c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c=$( printf '%s - %s\n' "$a" "$b" | bc )
```

or, for the lazy,

```
c=$( echo "$a - $b" | bc )
```

or, for the lazy `bash` user,

```
c=$( bc <<<"$a - $b" )
```

---

The issue with your code is that

```
c=$((a-b)) | bc
```

won't work.  You can only (usefully) pipe things that produces output, and `c=$((a-b))` is an assignment that 1) will fail if `$a` or `$b` are floating point numbers (with a syntax error), and 2) does not produce output.  Furthermore, the output from `bc` (nothing) will not be assigned to `c` since it's not part of the assignment at all.

Comment: if you can help me with floating number comparison also , will be awesome.I am trying to do 

if [ bc <<< "$c -gt 0"]
then
....
fi

Comment: @AviteshKesharwani That's a new question though.